# Java Logger. Suppress the junk (data/time/etc.)

Tags: java, logging, printing, formatting, system.out

I know this question was asked hundreds of times, however I am a beginner in programming(tried all the suggestions,but couldn't succeed) and
would like to have a more *step-by-step* explanation of how this problem can be fixed.

I am using **Java Loggers**  *instead of* **System.out** in my program as following:

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TheNameOfMyProgram.class.getName());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "The number A: " + numberA);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "The number B: " + numberB);
```

And this is what I get for the output:

```
    Oct 25, 2013 11:43:02 PM mypackage.TheNameOfMyProgram methodName
    INFO: The number A: 10
    Oct 25, 2013 11:43:02 PM mypackage.TheNameOfMyProgram methodName
    INFO: The number A: 20
```

I want the output to look in **System.out** kind of fashion:

```
    The number A: 10
    The number B: 20
```

What do I do to achieve this? I know that I will probably need to create a separate class 
let's say **LogFormatter** and then call it to print **A** and **B**
So, could you guys please explain me how to create that **LogFormatter** and how to
call it in order to have the *desired* output.

Please help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `java.util.logging` configs are using `SimpleFormatter`, you can change the format string in the config files.  See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) for details.

The Oracle documentation is "sparse" (IMO).  The best online "tutorial" article I could find on writing `java.util.logging` configuration files is http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html

---

It is worth nothing that most people use a 3rd party logging library rather than `java.util.logging`.  The most popular ones are log4j 1.2 and logback.  If you want to insulate your (reusable) code from the choice of logging framework, then look at the slf4j facade library.